# Could not set thread-stack size in mysql

Tags: mysql, multithreading, my.cnf

I'm trying to increase [thread-stack](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html) variable. I can do it successfully using command-line option as such:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --thread-stack=256k
```

I can also do it using configuration files `/etc/init/mysql.conf` or `/etc/init.d/mysql`:

```
thread_stack=262144
thread_stack=256k
thread-stack=256k
thread-stack=262144
```

However, setting through `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` doesn't work. `show variables like'%thread_stack%';` still shows the default `196608`.

**Why** does setting through `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` not work?

How do I fix this?

(MySQL 5.5, 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log.)

Comment: Maybe you've got a line `thread-stack=196608` right below the file or maybe in some other ini file that overwrites your setting. Does searching for `stack` show up anything?

Comment: @gobwas How did you get it resolved? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: Posted here : http://serverfault.com/questions/704068/my-cnf-file-does-not-reflect-changes-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @KillABug did not fixed this, If I remember right =(

Comment: @Pacerier thanks, but I can not try it, this task is out of date already =(

Comment: @gobwas Fixed it. I had multiple processes running for mysql. I had use `kill -15 -1` to kill all application processes and restart the mysql server and apache. The file was updated then

Comment: @KillABug could you post this as an answer? Looks like it really potential solution of my case too )

Answer (score 1):

The issue was multiple processes(threads) running for mysql. The output of `pgrep` in the question led me to use `kill -15 -1`.

This kills all the active processes for applications. Then I had to restart mysql and apache and I had the value updated.