# MySql - Thread_stack size not changing in wamp

Tags: mysql, wamp

I want to execute a recursive stored procedure, 
I've also specified depth of recursion this way :

```
SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
```

But **sometimes** I face with this error while executing my query :

> QUERY:CALL GetHighestParent(149);FAILED DUE TOThread stack overrun: 
>   136496 bytes used of a 262144 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed. 
>   Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

I tried to specify a bigger **thread_stack** with this command :

```
mysqld --thread-stack=5k
```

Also I tried

```
mysqld --thread-stack=500000
```

But When I restart wamp and execute this query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%thread_stack%';
```

I see that nothing has changed and the current **thread_stack** is **262144**
How should I solve this?

> These are my system Specifications:
>
> - Wamp 3.1.9 64bit
> - MySql Version : 5.7.26
> - Platform : Windows 10 X64

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not set thread-stack size in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762491/could-not-set-thread-stack-size-in-mysql)

Comment: @LV98 Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

You can change it here :

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Or If you are using **wamp** You can change it here :

```
\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql\my.ini
```

below of :

```
[wampmysqld64]
```

And restart Mysql.

Good Luck

Comment: where is **etc** ? I do not have such file __mysqld.cnf__ in my hard disk !

Comment: Oh , you are using wamp , sorry you can change it in : 

Drive:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql\my.ini

Comment: I changed it and restarted my wamp but nothing has happend.

Comment: Could you please send your my.ini or my.cnf ?

Comment: I've uploaded here __https://drive.google.com/file/d/14vAirOpRQ4W35BvS9_-tNr1VkNYyLgWD/view__

Comment: also see this please __https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gE5fzhvVBSql2vFDSTsYCwzCsurE6xcg/view?usp=sharing__

Comment: You should past config below of : [wampmysqld64] . Because this config belongs to mysqld.